# Conversão Java para Objective-C

Tags: java, ios, objective-c

Necessito da conversão deste pequeno código em Java para Objective-C para executar uma função no Objective-C, porém possui um erro que ainda não consegui descobrir.

Código Java:

```
final char CHR0 = 0;
String finalprotocolo = "" + CHR0 + "";

String ligartv = "/ARP/IR/enviar/LigaTV" + finalprotocolo;
byte[] arrayligartv = ligartv.getBytes();
```

Código Objective-C:

```
    unichar c = 0x00;// c = 0x00;
    NSString *nova = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c];
    //NSString *nova = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
    // Pega a menssagem<br>
    NSString *final = @"/ARP/enviar/LigaTV";
    NSString *mensagem = [final stringByAppendingString:nova];
```

Preciso realizar a mesma função do código Java, apenas transformando o byte 0 em String e adicionando a variável mensagem do Objective-C.

Comment: Qual erro está acontecendo?

Comment: Uso este código para executar determina função no Arduino e com o código Java ele funciona, mas com Objective-C não. Teria alguma peculiaridade na linguagem em questão ou é erro de código mesmo? @PauloRodrigues

Answer (score 1):

> Preciso realizar a mesma função do código Java, apenas transformando o byte 0 em String e adicionando a variável mensagem do Objective-C.

Um exemplo de transformar um unichar em NSString seria como código abaixo:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     unichar unicharA = 0x0391;
     NSLog(@"converterUnichar = %@", [self converterUnichar:unicharA])
}
-(NSString*) converterUnichar:(unichar) c{
     NSString *stringRetorno = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
     return stringRetorno;
}
```

Seria somente isso mesmo?
Espero ter ajudado, abraço

Comment: Estou fazendo desta forma @revton
   `unichar c = 0x00;`   
   `NSString *nova = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];`

Pode ser?

Comment: Eu criei um método com a sua solução porém não funciono, eu usaria da forma que eu postei.
-(NSString*) converterUnicharUser75138:(unichar) c{
    NSString *nova = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
    return nova;
}